# Centering a tabular environment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a table imported using the `eststo` package in Stata that isn't centering using the usual `\centering` command:

```
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{inc\_margin}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{inc\_margin}\\
\hline
incterms    &      -3.115         &      -2.967\sym{*}  \\
            &     (-2.03)         &     (-2.54)         \\
[1em]
RDI\_1       &     -0.0457         &                     \\
            &     (-0.07)         &                     \\
[1em]
RDI\_2       &       0.115         &                     \\
            &      (0.15)         &                     \\
[1em]
RDI\_3       &       0.374         &       0.438         \\
            &      (0.35)         &      (0.51)         \\
[1em]
RDI\_4       &       4.104\sym{***}&       4.095\sym{***}\\
            &      (5.07)         &      (5.73)         \\
[1em]
\_cons      &      -1.143         &      -1.332         \\
            &     (-0.25)         &     (-0.33)         \\
\hline
\(N\)       &          17         &          17         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code complete with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but it's necessary to understand your problem and help you.

Comment: Where exactly did you place the `\centering'? Make sure it's outside the outermost brackets.

Comment: Assuming you inserted a `\centering` instruction immediately after the opening curly brace, you *must* leave at least one blank line (or provide an explicit `\par` instruction) between `\end{tabular}` and the closing curly brace.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to centering the `tabular` environment, you may also want to give some thought to making the appearance of the table more visually appealing than what's provided by the `eststo` Stata package. Among possible improvements are (a) aligning of numbers on the decimal markers, (b) use of better-spaced horizontal lines, i.e., non-use of `\hline` and `\hline\hline`, and (c) less-extravagant amounts of whitespace between pairs of rows; I suggest you use `\\[1ex]` instead of `\\[1em]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{document}
{\centering
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{d{3.5}}} % use 'd' column type instead of 'c'
\toprule % don't use `\hline\hline` and `\hline`
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)}\\
& \mc{inc\_margin} & \mc{inc\_margin}\\
\midrule
incterms  &      -3.115    &      -2.967\sym{*}  \\
          &     (-2.03)    &     (-2.54)         \\[1ex]
RDI\_1    &     -0.0457    &                     \\
          &     (-0.07)    &                     \\[1ex]
RDI\_2    &       0.115    &                     \\
          &      (0.15)    &                     \\[1ex]
RDI\_3    &       0.374    &       0.438         \\
          &      (0.35)    &      (0.51)         \\[1ex]
RDI\_4    &       4.104\sym{***}&       4.095\sym{***}\\
          &      (5.07)         &      (5.73)         \\[1ex]
\_cons    &      -1.143         &      -1.332         \\
          &     (-0.25)         &     (-0.33)         \\
\midrule
\(N\)     &        \mc{17}      &     \mc{17}    \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t}-statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\par % <--- this is needed
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment `\begin{center}...\end{center}` or leave a blank line after `\centering` (that must be outside the `tabular` environment).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{inc\_margin}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{inc\_margin}\\
\hline
incterms    &      -3.115         &      -2.967\sym{*}  \\
            &     (-2.03)         &     (-2.54)         \\
[1em]
RDI\_1       &     -0.0457         &                     \\
            &     (-0.07)         &                     \\
[1em]
RDI\_2       &       0.115         &                     \\
            &      (0.15)         &                     \\
[1em]
RDI\_3       &       0.374         &       0.438         \\
            &      (0.35)         &      (0.51)         \\
[1em]
RDI\_4       &       4.104\sym{***}&       4.095\sym{***}\\
            &      (5.07)         &      (5.73)         \\
[1em]
\_cons      &      -1.143         &      -1.332         \\
            &     (-0.25)         &     (-0.33)         \\
\hline
\(N\)       &          17         &          17         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```